# refresh activity after startactivityforresult and contextmenu changes

Tags: android, android-activity

I am trying to use a contact picker using     startactivityforresult() and want to refresh my settings page once the activity is resumed which displays the selected contacts in the database. My     onResume() is therefore simply same as onCreate(). So i copied my onCreate code in an overriden     onResume() as it is.

There are two issues i am facing-
 1. The listview details are being duplicated
 2. The refresh method seems to very redundant in nature

Can someone suggest me a good method to refresh my activity. I also want to refresh after a listview item deletion using contextmenu - it does not seem to happen even with duplicated onResume().

EDIT:-
some clarification

On selecting Contact 1 the list shows two items Contact 1 and Contact 1 though the db has one non duplicate entry of Contact 1 (the listview is designed to show the names of contacts that have been copied to the database).

When the activity starts, the listview is populated by the db showing the names of the contacts that have been added. A cursor receives the db column and populates the listview programatically. I want this to happen every time the db is changed - a new contact is added or a contact is removed via a contextmenu on long click.

The redundancy is that is there any way (neater) other than simply copying the same code as onCreate to onResume.

```
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

           setContentView(R.layout.setting);
           TabHost th = (TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
           th.setup();

           spec1 = th.newTabSpec("tag1");
           spec1.setIndicator("CONTACTS");

           try {

               db = this.openOrCreateDatabase("App_Database",MODE_PRIVATE , null);
               Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("SELECT NAME FROM Contacts_Table",null);    
               cur.moveToFirst();    
               String first = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("NAME"));
               if(cur.isNull(cur.getColumnIndex("NAME")) || first.equals(null) ){
                     setAddContactTab();     
                    }

               else{ 
                      Log.e("first name" , first);
                      populateContactsList();

                   }

              }catch(SQLiteException e){

                  setAddContactTab();

              }

           th.addTab(spec1);

           TabSpec spec2 = th.newTabSpec("tag2");
           spec2.setContent(R.id.tab2);
           ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.variable_list);  
           lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.variables)));
           spec2.setIndicator("VARIABLES");
           th.addTab(spec2);


           TabSpec spec3 = th.newTabSpec("tag3");
           spec3.setContent(R.id.tab3);
           et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.webaddress);
           SharedPreferences webad = getSharedPreferences(filename,0);
           et.setText(webad.getString("tvalue",""));   
           spec3.setIndicator("WEBSITE");
           th.addTab(spec3);

    }
```

Comment: Try calling `Log.d("my app", "onResume")` in your onResume.  Can you clarify your second question? I think we need more code to understand why your refresh method is redundant. How are you getting data into the ListView? e.g. A custom BaseAdapter, CursorAdapter? ArrayAdapter?

Answer (score 2):

Do your list creation only in onResume, it is called every time, even on initial startup.

Comment: worked that out with a debug.. should have done it before posting the problem. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using [invalidate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate%28%29) after your method returns?

```
ViewGroup vg = findViewById (R.id.mainLayout);
vg.invalidate();
```

Comment: my view is as shown in the code of the post edit. How do i invalidate the above before/after startactivityforresult and db change from contextmenu ?

Comment: invalidate the layout directly after your startactivityforresult call, so that when that method returns your activity layout will redraw itself